# Execute command from Java code deployed on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, windows, apache, batch-file, tomcat

I was trying to convert a DOCX file to PDF file, found this vb script code which perfectly converts DOCX to PDF file, it uses .bat file for file generation. The code can be executed through java.

I am facing a strange problem, when I execute the code on my local machine, the file is generated, but when I deployed the app on Server , the code executes with no errors but the file is not generated.

Do we need any permission to execute commands through java?

Following is the details:

Server Operating system : Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Application server      :Apache Tomcat 7.0.75

Code:
1)Java

```
 public static void generatePDF() {
    try {

        File file = new File("C:\\Docx_To_Pdf_Converter\\errorLog.txt");
        PrintStream printStreamToFile = new PrintStream(file);
        System.setOut(printStreamToFile);


        String docToPdf = "C:\\Docx_To_Pdf_Converter\\doc2pdf.bat";

        File docPath = new File("C:\\Docx_To_Pdf_Converter\\Letter1.docx");

        File pdfPath = new File("C:\\Docx_To_Pdf_Converter\\LetterPDF.pdf");

        String command = String.format("%s %s %s", docToPdf, docPath, pdfPath);

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        // The next line is optional and will force the current Java 
        //thread to block until the script has finished its execution.

        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {      
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and the .bat file code:

```
@Echo off
pushd %~dp0
cscript C:\Docx_To_Pdf_Converter\doc2pdf.vbs %1 %2
```

vbscript code which actually converts the docx to pdf

```
Const wdFormatPDF = 17  ' PDF format. 
Const wdFormatXPS = 18  ' XPS format. 
Const WdDoNotSaveChanges = 0

Dim arguments
Set arguments = WScript.Arguments


Function CheckUserArguments()
If arguments.Unnamed.Count < 1 Or arguments.Unnamed.Count > 2 Then
WScript.Echo "Use:"
WScript.Echo "<script> input.doc"
WScript.Echo "<script> input.doc output.pdf"
WScript.Quit 1
End If
End Function

// Transforms a doc to a pdf
Function DocToPdf( docInputFile, pdfOutputFile )

Dim fileSystemObject
Dim wordApplication
Dim wordDocument
Dim wordDocuments
Dim baseFolder

Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wordDocuments = wordApplication.Documents
docInputFile = fileSystemObject.GetAbsolutePathName(docInputFile)
baseFolder = fileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName(docInputFile)
If Len(pdfOutputFile) = 0 Then
pdfOutputFile = fileSystemObject.GetBaseName(docInputFile) + ".pdf"

End If

If Len(fileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName(pdfOutputFile)) = 0 Then
pdfOutputFile = baseFolder + "\" + pdfOutputFile

End If
//' Disable any potential macros of the word document.
wordApplication.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
// 'from below line the code does not executes
Set wordDocument = wordDocuments.Open(docInputFile) 
wordDocument.SaveAs pdfOutputFile, wdFormatPDF
wordDocument.Close WdDoNotSaveChanges
wordApplication.Quit WdDoNotSaveChanges

Set wordApplication = Nothing
Set fileSystemObject = Nothing
End Function
// ' Execute script
Call CheckUserArguments()
If arguments.Unnamed.Count = 2 Then
Call DocToPdf( arguments.Unnamed.Item(0), arguments.Unnamed.Item(1) )
Else
Call DocToPdf( arguments.Unnamed.Item(0), "" )
End If

Set arguments = Nothing
```

Comment: What is the server's operating system? Is the converter installed? Is it in the same directory? There is a lot of information missing in your question, and without it nobody can possibly help you.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.  Now put yourself in the position of someone being asked to help you, what information would YOU want to see in order to help?  Also, you haven't shown enough of your code... what happens if an exception is thrown? Do you catch it?

Comment: Hello Jim, sorry for short description, I have updated my code.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have edited my question as needed with details, still no updates or suggestions, is it because of the negative vote or any more information is needed? please let me know....Thank you.

Comment: Does `C:\\Docx_To_Pdf_Converter\\doc2pdf.bat` exists on the server (can you exeucte the bat-file on the server, without Java)? You could put some debug.logs/echos in your bat-file to see where it hangs... (In general, you should also use ProcessBuilder, when dealing with arguments, instead of Runtime.exec...)

Comment: @Ben Yes C:\\Docx_To_Pdf_Converter\\doc2pdf.bat exists on server. The code executes when run from DOS cmd prompt or Java . I am  facing problem when I deploy it using Apache Tomcat on server. I have updated the code with vbScript code hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give you a 100% guaranteed answer as we don't have access to your deployment server, but here's what I think is happening there.

If the `.bat` file were missing or not executable for some reason, then you would get an `IOException` in your Java code.  Since you didn't get an exception, clearly the `.bat` file was found and executed.

However, whatever is *within* the `.bat` file is not being executed as you expect.  Either `cscript.exe` is missing, or the `.vbs` file is missing.  The way your code is written, ***you would not be aware of this***.  All you would see is a non-zero status return from the `waitfor()` method, and you don't bother to check that.  Therefore you have no knowledge of what *actually* happened.

At the very minimum you should change the `waitfor()` method invocation to:

```
int rc = process.waitFor();
System.out.printf("Process returned %d\n", rc);
```

This will tell you the return status from the attempt to execute the `.bat` file. If it's not zero, then you have a problem, and I'm 99.999% sure you will find this to be non-zero.  To troubleshoot this you will need to capture the output from the command.  The following is a ***highly simplified*** (as in no error handling; that's up to you) example:

```
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader procOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = procOutput.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
        // Or whatever you need to do to in your environment, such
        // as log the output or examine it to ensure the script did
        // what you want
    }
    int rc = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.printf("Process returned %d\n", rc);
```

***NOTE***  The above is not production-level code, it is only an example of how to use the API.  This works ONLY if the external command requires no redirected input; if it does require input then you need to handle input and output in separate threads to prevent deadlocks.

Also, you should consider using `ProcessBuilder` as it is much more flexible.  For example, it allows you to redirect the process' output to append to a log file, which you should probably implement.

Comment: As you suggested I checked the return value it is 0 "zero" , I have update the vbScript code aswell and added a comment from where the code is skiped. But when I execute it using dos cmd promt or java the entire code is executed and file is generated, this does not happen when I run the application on server using Apache Tomcat as web application. Do we nee any permission while installing Tomcat on Server? please let me know .. Thank you for your hel